# How to load a Javascript asset depending on controller/action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the default `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

CoffeeScript templates have this content:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
```

For me, "***related to the matching controller here***" means that `foo_bar.js.coffee` should ONLY be loaded when the `foo_bar` controller is used. Am I right?

Thing is that it loads all Javascript files even if they are not needed. Also... I would like to know how to conditionally include Javascript files depending on the controller's action.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of ways to do this, the easiest and most elegant way I have found is this:

Remove the

```
//= require_tree .
```

Directive, and change your template to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller_name %>
```

Then load your global js in application, and controller specific in controller_name.

For instance, if you are in posts_controller, you will get posts.js or posts.js.coffee loaded.

**EDIT**

To do the action, you can also add

```
action_name
```

to my proposed solution. One thing you may consider, is breaking it out into application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :your_function

def your_function
  @controller = controller_name
  @action = action_name
end
```

Then using it like this in your layout

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "#@controller.#@action" %>
```

Comment: Cool, this is how the generated skeleton should have been done. What about actions? I mean... I would like to load a JavaScript only for an specific action... is it also possible to do in an easy way?

Answer (score 3):

The `require_tree` directive in your `application.js` loads all js and coffee files found in your assets tree. If you remove it it will only load the specified files.

> For me, "related to the matching controller here" means that foo_bar.js.coffee should ONLY be loaded when the foo_bar controller is used. Am I right?

No, files are loaded as specified via "require" directives.

> Also... I would like to know how to conditionally include Javascript files depending on the controller's action.

Make a `foo_bar.js` file for each controller, in each require other files as needed, and conditionally include them in your layout

```
# some_layout.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```